# How to show new line in label

Tags: asp.net

below is my code i am new to asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
lbl.Text="India\r\nis\r\nbest";
    }
```

The result comes: `India is best`
but require result is with newline

```
India
is
best
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply try this

```
lbl.Text="India\r\nis\r\nbest".Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lbl.Text="India<br/>is<br/>best";
```